# How to install django-haystack using buildout

Tags: python, buildout

I'm trying to convert a current Django project in development to use zc.buildout  So far, I've got all the bits figured except for Haystack figured out.

The Haystack source is available on GitHub, but I don't want to force users to install git.  A suitable alternative seems to be to fetch a tarball from [here](http://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/tarball/master)

That tarball contains a setuptools setup.py, and it seems like it should be so *easy* to get buildout to install it.  Halp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they've fixed the package to work from the tarball. James' fork is not working right now, but you can use the same recipe passing it the standard url:

```
[haystack]
recipe = collective.recipe.distutils
url = http://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/tarball/master
```

This worked for me and is 100% hack free.

Answer (score 4):

I figured this one out, without posting it to PyPI.  (There is no actually tagged release version of django-haystack, so posting to to PyPI seems unclean.  It's something the maintainer should and probably will handle better themselves.)

The relevant section is as follows:

```
[haystack]
recipe = collective.recipe.distutils
url = http://github.com/ephelon/django-haystack/tarball/master
```

I had to create a fork of the project to remove `zip_safe=False` from setup.py.  Once I'd done that the above works flawlessly, even the redirect sent by the above url.

Comment: NB: I've migrated away from Django (and Haystack) for this project, and I'm no longer maintaining this fork.

Answer (score 2):

This currently works for me without forking.

```
[django-haystack]
recipe = zerokspot.recipe.git
repository = git://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git
as_egg = true

[whoosh]
recipe = zerokspot.recipe.git
repository = git://github.com/toastdriven/whoosh.git
branch = haystacked
as_egg = true
```

Make sure you add the locations to your `extra-paths`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want to install GIT, you can't check it out. So then you have to download a release. But there aren't any. In theory, find-links directly to the distribution should work. In this case it wont, probably because you don't link to the file, but to a page that generates the file from the trunk. So that option was out.

So, you need to bribe somebody to make a release, or make one yourself. You can make a release and stick it in a file server somewhere, and then use find-links in the buildout to point to the right place.

Or, since nobody else seems to have released Haystack to PyPI, you can do it! (But be nice and tell the developers and give them manager rights to the package as well).